# Dropdown Menu for Small Screens not linking well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my menu as:

```
<nav> 
    <ul> 
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and a supporting JQuery to help fire the functionality as:

```
$(function() {
    // Create the dropdown base
    $("<select />").appendTo("nav");
    // Create default option "Go to..."
    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Go to..."
    }).appendTo("nav select");
    // Populate dropdown with menu items
    $("nav > ul > li").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var hasChildren = el.find("ul"),
                children = el.find("li");
        if (hasChildren.length) {
            $("<optgroup />", {
                "label": el.find("> a").text()
            }).appendTo("nav select");
            children.each(function() {
                $("<option />", {
                    "text": " - " + $(this).text()
                }).appendTo("optgroup:last");
            });
        } else {
            $("<option />", {
                "value": el.attr("href"),
                "text": el.text()
            }).appendTo("nav select");
        }
    });
    // To make dropdown actually work
    $("nav select").change(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
});
```

The problem here is that when I select any of the menus it does not link properly. The returned URL on the browser is eg `www.example.com/One` instead of `www.example.com/#`

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `.text()` to get the contents of an a element. 
For example:

```
el.find("> a").text()
```

Instead of text, use `attr("href")`, as in:

```
el.find("> a").attr("href");
```

Per jQuery documentation: 
The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

Now, I've created a JSFiddle to test your code out, and this will make it work:

```
$(function() {
    // Create the dropdown base
    $("<select />").appendTo("nav");
    // Create default option "Go to..."
    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Go to..."
    }).appendTo("nav select");
    // Populate dropdown with menu items
    $("nav > ul > li").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var hasChildren = el.find("ul"),
                children = el.find("li");
        if (hasChildren.length) {
            $("<optgroup />", {
                "label": el.find("> a").text()
            }).appendTo("nav select");
            children.each(function() {
                console.log($(this).find("> a").attr("href"));
                $("<option />", {
                    "text": " - " + $(this).text(), 
                    "value": $(this).find("> a").attr("href")
                }).appendTo("optgroup:last");
            });
        } else {
            $("<option />", {
                "value": el.find("> a").attr("href"),
                "text": el.text()
            }).appendTo("nav select");
        }
    });
    // To make dropdown actually work
    $("nav select").change(function() {
        //console.log($(this).find("option:selected").val());
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
});
```

You can test and play around with the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S75Mt/) too.

There were also some .find("> a") missing from the previous version.

Comment: At what point because I am still getting the same error. I changed `"label": el.find("> a").text()` to `"label": el.find("> a").attr("href")` and it still didn't work out fine.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the right fix. Try it out on JSFiddle!